# How to write a file at custom path in external SD card in Android 6.0

Tags: java, android, file-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I mean the followings in this question:

internal SD card: the on-board storage device whose path is obtainable from calling `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

external SD card: a physical microSD card that can be inserted to or removed from the device's microSD card slot

---

I am developing in Android 6.0 Marshmallow.

I heard that we cannot write at a custom path in external SD card in Android Lollipop, but we can write at a custom path in external SD card in Android Marshmallow.

I added the permission
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
in the Android manifest.
I also requested the runtime permission by calling the function `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissionArray, requestCode)`.

Now. I can read/write a file in the internal SD card (a path like `/storage/emulated/0/...`).
My problem is, that I cannot write a file in the external SD card (a path like `/storage/0000-0000/...`).
If I try to write a file in the external SD card, the following exception occurs:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/0000-0000/Pictures/abc.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:127)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116)
    ...
```

I have searched this problem in StackOverflow, but the questions/answers were all about the runtime permission in Android 6.0, which is not my case.

How can I write a file at a custom path in the external SD card in Android 6.0?

---

**EDIT**

To be clear, what I have is the path of a file to write (like a string `"/storage/0000-0000/Pictures/abc.jpg"`), and I can use `FileOutputStream` to write the content.

Comment: You are never allowed to write to the whole micro SD card. Only to your app specific directory like ......../Android/data/<packagename>. Try getExternalFilesDirs() to find that path. It will be the second entry. ..FilesDirs not ...FilesDir.

Comment: @greenapps Doesn't it apply only to Android 4.4 and 5.x?

Comment: No. It does not as far as i know. But maybe you can use the Storage Access Framework.